# VBA: How to keep a form open for a set amount of seconds

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a member sign in program using VBA and Microsoft Access. So i have the user enter their information and then everything is inserted into my database tables. After I do that I want to display a form with some information back to the user. However, I only want it to stay up for maybe 15 seconds and then close. Is there a way to do that?

Here's a snippet of what I tried. Essentially I opened the form and then set a timer to close the form. When I do it this way the form is never actually displayed to the user. Any reason for this? It does show if I remove the close in the last line.

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

    [Forms]![SwipeServiceDatesHidden].Requery

    currentTime = Now()
    setTime = currentTime + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Do While currentTime < setTime
        currentTime = Now()
    Loop

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "SwipeServiceDatesHidden", acSaveNo

    End Sub
```

Comment: the way i've done it in the past is with `application.ontime setTime,"subToCloseForm"` rather than a loop.

Comment: Not sure about Access, but for Excel, I can auto unload UserForm by `Application.OnTime` to call a Sub in normal module which unloads the UserForm.

Comment: Where is the `Close` line?

Comment: Sorry must have deleted the close line while reformatting. It's back in now.

Comment: Do I need to install a package to use Application.OnTime? I'm getting a compile error that says method or data member not found.

Comment: To add to ballsy26's answer. Put your DoCmd.Close statement in a separate Sub called subToCloseForm. Put this statement in your Form_Load:
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "subToCloseForm"

Comment: If it is only 15 seconds, you could use a loop which repeatedly tests `Timer` (relative to a fixed time) with the body of the loop simply `DoEvents` so that the form will remain responsive to user input.

Comment: Application.OnTime is not available in access VBA

Answer (score 1):

putting all the prior comments together

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    setTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")    

    Application.OnTime setTime, "subToCloseForm"

End Sub

Sub subToCloseForm

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.OnTime` is not available in access VBA

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27034755/Application-OnTime-in-Access.html this looks like an alternative to `application.ontime`